# Plugin installation fails because required items are missing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I tried to install `Web Tool Platform` for Eclipse but I can not succeed due to the following error.

> Cannot complete
>   the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: CXF Web Services
>   1.1.0.v201201312103-7H79FHxFAKlbotH5e9l3vAA6MBG (org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group
>   1.1.0.v201201312103-7H79FHxFAKlbotH5e9l3vAA6MBG)   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.501.v201108102200
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.501.v201108102200) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.501.v201109131730
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.501.v201109131730) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.600.v201203142300
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.600.v201203142300) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.600.v201205030130
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.600.v201205030130) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.600.v201205170400
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.600.v201205170400) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Missing requirement: Java EE Component 1.1.601.v201207101600
>   (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 1.1.601.v201207101600) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: CXF Web Services Core 1.1.0.v201205012246 (org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core 1.1.0.v201205012246)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.jst.j2ee [1.1.0,1.2.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: CXF Web Services 1.1.0.v201201312103-7H79FHxFAKlbotH5e9l3vAA6MBG (org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group
>   1.1.0.v201201312103-7H79FHxFAKlbotH5e9l3vAA6MBG)
>       To: org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core [1.1.0.v201205012246]

Actually this happens a lot of times when I try to install additional software via `Help > Install New Software`. E.g. I had it some times when trying to install the Android SDK.
Though I could usually solve it while fiddling around with it I can't believe installing plug ins is such a pain.

So I think I might missing some very basic things but I can not find a hint. So it would be a great if you could help me to fix this particular problem but also provide some information how to tackle such problems in a more general matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the bottom of the "Install" dialog, make sure that "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" is checked.

[image: Eclipse Install Dialog]

This assumes that the necessary, default software sites are still properly configured (haven't been disabled, removed, etc.) and available.  These are configured under Windows, Preferences, Install/Update, Available Software Sites.  (Unfortunately, I don't see a "restore to defaults" button here.)  For at least the latest version of Eclipse (4.2/Juno), you'll want to ensure you have at least the following sites configured and enabled here:

- Juno : http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
- The Eclipse Project Updates : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2
- The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository : http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno