# Eclipse WTP installation fails "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I followed the answer's instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330835/plugin-installation-fails-because-required-items-are-missing) but the issue persists. I have Juno and trying to download WTP SDK 3.1.2 (Not sure if that's what I'm supposed to download. Tried other things but none worked) from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/), and get the error message

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JST Enterprise Plug-in Developer Resources 3.1.1.v200908101600-771184eAHSuuJTW3Ue6ZhBIyV8tu (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_sdk.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908101600-771184eAHSuuJTW3Ue6ZhBIyV8tu)
  Missing requirement: J2EE Core Component 1.1.301.v200908181930 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core 1.1.301.v200908181930) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4,4.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: J2EE Core Component 1.1.301.v200911302230 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core 1.1.301.v200911302230) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4,4.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WTP EJB UI Plug-in 1.1.301.v200908131325 (org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui 1.1.301.v200908131325)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core [1.1.0,1.2.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JST Enterprise Plug-in Developer Resources 3.1.1.v200908101600-771184eAHSuuJTW3Ue6ZhBIyV8tu (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_sdk.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908101600-771184eAHSuuJTW3Ue6ZhBIyV8tu)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group [3.1.1.v200908101600-7_7EGrjFQRwRb4P511ebObS5XZhq]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.1.1.v200908101600-7_7EGrjFQRwRb4P511ebObS5XZhq (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908101600-7_7EGrjFQRwRb4P511ebObS5XZhq)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.ejb.ui [1.1.301.v200908131325]
```

Comment: You will need to detail what you are installing into (version, package type, etc.), what your installing from and the full error message that you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler), make sure you have the following two update sites:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3

Comment: I have Juno and I added the needed sites